# INI Reader crashes when reading if the value is missing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use this C# INI Reader.

https://gist.github.com/Sn0wCrack/5891612

---

It works well, I'm able to write

```
INIFile inif = new INIFile(@"C:\Path\To\example.ini");

inif.Write("Example Section", "Example_Key_Text", (vm.Example_Key_Text));
```

and read

```
string example = inif.Read("Example Section", "Example_Key_Text");
```

INI file output:

```
[Example Section]
Example_Key_Text=This is a test.
```

---

**Problem**

When reading, the program crashes if the `[Section]` or `Key` is missing in the `ini` file.

I believe it is crashing on `GetPrivateProfileString()`.

This happens if I add a `read` for a new control and the program uses the old `ini` file where the value missing. I would like it to be able to still use an old file and just ignore if the value is missing instead of crashing.

I could use a `try/catch` but I don't know if I want to do that on every `read`, I have about 100 of them from the file.

---

**INI Reader**

```
public partial class INIFile
{
    public string path { get; private set; }

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string val, string filePath);
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);

    public INIFile(string INIPath)
    {
        path = INIPath;
    }
    public void Write(string Section, string Key, string Value)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
    }

    public string Read(string Section, string Key)
    {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
        return temp.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use one of the NuGet package INI readers? [This one is apparently 100% .NET code](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/).

Comment: Can you post the exception details (type, message and stack trace)? I don't think `GetPrivateProfileString()` itself raises any exception, all error return values are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring) But if so, you could change the `Read` method to catch this exception and return a default or empty string instead.

Comment: @John Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: @RenéVogt The exception says `Input string was not in the correct format.`

Comment: Then please check the stack trace! The exception is not raised by this ini reader, but later when you try to use the returned string. This has nothing to do with the code you posted, I tested it. But of course, if the value isn't there in the file, you get an empty string. And for example `int.Parse("")` will throw exactly the exception you see. So there's your problem, not in reading the file. Try `int.TryParse()` instead.

Comment: @RenéVogt Thanks, I will try `int.TryParse()`, I was confused to where the error was happening.

Comment: Next time, please include that in your question :)

Comment: @RenéVogt Everything is working now, I had to change all the `bool` and `double` I had in `read` with `TryParse()`.